# Listando arquivos de pastas com PHP

Tags: php

Olá fiz esse programinha que lista as fotos do meu diretório , só que queria que ao clicar no lista da foto aparece-se a foto em tela com php.

```
 <?php

 $path = "C:\FOTOS COOPERADOS 2013";
   $diretorio = dir($path);

    echo "Lista de Arquivos do diretório '<strong>".$path."</strong>':<br />";    
   while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()){
      echo "<a href='".$path.$arquivo."'>".$arquivo."</a><br />";
   }
   $diretorio -> close();
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ja tentou assim? echo "<a href='".$arquivo."'>".$arquivo."</a><br />";

Comment: sim dar o seguinte erro Objeto não encontrado!

A URL requisitada não foi encontrada neste servidor. O link na página referida parece estar com algum erro ou desatualizado. Por favor informe o autor desta página sobre o erro.

Comment: Ok, mostre como fica o link de uma uma imagem que não abre

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sobre o `select` você pode colocar tudo num `array` ou buscar os valores no banco de dados se tiver, coloquei um exemplo com `array`:

```
<?php

$perspectiva = array();

$perspectiva[1] = "Financeiro";
$perspectiva[2] = "Comercial";
$perspectiva[3] = "Administrativo";
$perspectiva[4] = "Cooperados";
$perspectiva[5] = "Aprendizagem";
$perspectiva[6] = "Rede";
$perspectiva[7] = "Assistencia Hospitalar";
$perspectiva[8] = "Comunicaçao e Marketing";

?>

<?php if( is_array($perspectiva) and count($perspectiva) > 0 ){ ?> 
    <select name="perspectiva">
        <?php foreach( $perspectiva as $key => $value ){ ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $value; ?></option>

        <?php } ?>
    </select> 
<?php } ?>


<?php

// Exemplo de como recuperar o valor
$o_que_quero_mostrar = 6; // Rede   

echo $perspectiva[$o_que_quero_mostrar];

?>
```

Comment: E para listar no lugar do array o meu banco de dados como que poderia está fazendo ?

Comment: @allanaraujo Você fará um consulta normal ao banco de dados, se não me engano o mysql_fetch_array te retornará esse array, mas não tenho certeza, tenta fazer caso não conseguir abra outro tópico com suas dúvidas.

Comment: Obrigado você ajudou muito .

Answer (score 0):

Utilizar barra normal ao invés de barra invertida em `$path`, além disso, acrescentar uma barra no final.

O que está assim:

```
$path = "C:\FOTOS COOPERADOS 2013";
```

deve ficar assim:

```
$path = "C:/FOTOS COOPERADOS 2013/";
```

Em seguida, adicione o prefixo `file:///`, pois trata-se de um arquivo local.

O que está assim:

```
echo "<a href='".$path.$arquivo."'>".$arquivo."</a><br />";
```

Deve ficar assim:

```
echo "<a href='file:///".$path.$arquivo."'>".$arquivo."</a><br />";
```

Veja o código completo:

```
<?php

    $path = "C:/FOTOS COOPERADOS 2013/";
    $diretorio = dir($path);
    echo "Lista de Arquivos do diretório '<strong>".$path."</strong>':<br />";    
    while($arquivo = $diretorio -> read()){
       echo "<a href='file:///".$path.$arquivo."'>".$arquivo."</a><br />";
    }
    $diretorio -> close();
```

Ao clicar no link, deve ser aberta uma URL similar a:

```
file:///C:/FOTOS%20COOPERADOS%202013/seu_arquivo.jpg
```

Comment: Ele lista , mas quando click no link que ele listou da imagem não abre nada . Como poderia está fazendo para exibir a imagem listada do diretório .

Comment: mostre como fica o endereço do arquivo quando não abre nada, copie e cole para nós o endereço do navegador.

Comment: atualizei a pergunta com a photo

Comment: seria assim file:///C:/FOTOS%20COOPERADOS%202013/Dr.%20Adilson%20Mota%20-%20Anestesiologia%20-%20HMU%201.JPG

Comment: sim . ele lista mais ao clicar no lonk para abrir a foto no navegador não abre

Comment: acontece o que quando clica no link?

Comment: Tente deixar tirar esses 20% da url assim: preg_replace("20%", " ", $path.$arquivo)

Comment: @AllanAndrade   Como posso imprimir com php o    Financeiro  , pois dou echo do ['perspectiva'] ela apenas imprimir o 1 mas quero que imprima o nome Finaceiro . Com posso fazer ?                                              <select name="perspectiva">
         <option value="1">Financeiro</option>
        </select>

Comment: @FabianoCacinPinel Como posso imprimir com php o    Financeiro  , pois dou echo do ['perspectiva'] ela apenas imprimir o 1 mas quero que imprima o nome Finaceiro . Com posso fazer ?                                              <select name="perspectiva">
         <option value="1">Financeiro</option>
        </select>

Comment: @allanaraujo não entendi o que você quis dizer, acho que você escreveu sua dúvida no tópico errado. Que Financeiro vc esta falando?

Comment: @FabianoCacinPinel o que coloquei na pergunta .

Comment: @allanaraujo, você deve alterar as perguntas apenas para esclarecer o objeto da mesma. Não deve incluir coisas que não tem nada a ver com a pergunta inicial. Peço novamente que dê uma lida na ajuda para entender como o site funciona. Fiz a reversão da pergunta para o assunto original.